# MySQL query to search database for products similar to a given product name

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I've looked into the Levenschein function, as well as other solutions but I think what I'm trying to do can be accomplished with one query.  I have written a function to remove common stopwords, then I've taken the important words and put them into an array to be used in the query.  Here is what I have so far.

```
$title = removecommonwords($itemtitle);
$title = explode (" ", $title);

$comparequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE (CONCAT(title, description) LIKE '%".$title."%') LIMIT 0,5 ORDER BY ...);
```

How could I order the results by the closest matches?

Comment: if this type of query is gonna become very common i suggest you look into solr this will provide much more efficient searching that like queries in a database

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your search if you fix the like clause you have an array in right now, but note you're going to be full table scanning as CONCAT() destroys the benefit of any indexes that exist on title or description.

`explode()` creates an array.  You either want to `implode()` to create a single string or you'll need \  to iterate through the $title array and call the query on each of the values... you can't stick an array like that into a like clause like that.

Mysql has no way of natively ordering by the percentage of how good a match from a like clause.